# Displaying image django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get image url from database by sending id in the request.

views.py

```
class RenderImage(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
            print(request.data)


    serializer = ImageSerializer(data = request.data)
        print(serializer.is_valid())
        print(request.data['id'])
        if(serializer.is_valid()):
            print("1")
            tags = serializer.data['id']
            output = {}
            images = Image.objects.get(pk = request.data['id'])
            print("2")
            # output['image'] = serializer.data
            for image in images:
                output.append(image.url)
            text = {'status': 1, 'data':output}
        else:
            text = {'status':-1, 'data':serializer.errors}
        return Response(text)
```

models.py

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.image.name)
```

serializers.py

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):#test

    class Meta:
        model = Image
```

in the views the serializer is invalid so the view doesn't proceed any idea whats wrong??

Comment: can you try get `print(serializer.errors)` after doing `serializer.is_valid()`

Comment: it gives me "no image was submitted"

Comment: You need to add either `MultiPartParser` or `FileUploadParser` to you REST_FRAMEWORK configs. [DRF parsers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser). Hope that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get image object use filter like this in your views....

```
img_url=Image.objects.filter(id=request.data['id'])
```

and now you can pass this in serializer to get data in json format